# jQuery Accordion failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am trying to implement a jQuery accordion into my webpage. It currently won't work. Any help would be appreciated hugely. Please bear in mind that I am a total novice and so it is likely I have made some very amateur mistakes.   However, I am trying to learn and I hope that with your knowledge I will be able to continue to do so. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//code.jQuery.com/jQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jQuery.com/ui/1.11.4/jQuery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jQuery.com/jQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jQuery.com/ui/1.11.4/jQuery-ui.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="accordion">

      <h3>Ice Cream Pancakes</h3>
      <div>
        <p>mmmmmmmmmmm</p>
      </div>

      <h3>Fruit Pancakes</h3>
      <div>
        <p>Not quite as nice, but acceptable</p>
      </div>

      <h3>Savoury Pancakes</h3>
      <div>
        <p>I had one once with chicken on, it was just odd!</p>
        <ol>
          <li>fried chicken</li>
          <li>pulled pork</li>
        </ol>
      </div>

      <h3>Non-Pancakes</h3>
      <div>
        <p>This is stuff that isn’t pancakes… like… cars and light bulbs…</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am also getting these errors:

```
Failed to load resource:
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (19:39:37:163 | error, network)
  at http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jQuery-ui.js

Failed to load resource:
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (19:39:37:199 | error, network)
  at http://code.jquery.com/jQuery-1.10.2.js

Failed to load resource:
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (19:39:37:217 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Check your `script`s. Your jQuery libaries links are invalid: 404 error http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jQuery-ui.js

Comment: The errors on your console indicate that the jQuery libraries could not be loaded. Fix those errors and try again.

Answer (score 0):

use `https://code.jQuery.com` instead of `//code.jQuery.com`

```
<script src="https://code.jQuery.com/jQuery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jQuery.com/ui/1.11.4/jQuery-ui.js"></script>
```

Instead of 4 lines, remove extra 2 lines and use them as above

Answer (score 0):

i don't see the accordion initialization

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
     });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to restate the obvious, everyone above is sort of right, you need to combine their answers.. here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgJxEW

1. You do not want to load the script twice
2. Make sure you get the script URL's right.. you should be able to visit the link and see the code
3. Init the function
4. You also will want to include one of the jquery ui css themes here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/ (I chose black tie as an example)

So, putting it all together

```
<head> 
// all of your other head tag code - only load this once 
<script src="//code.jQuery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jQuery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

// all of your html in the the body tag

// right before closing body tag 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

All of your scripts are failing to load because of the capital Q in the script name. Try these

```
    <script src="//code.jQuery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jQuery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: There should not be 4 scripts loaded to the page